# adb not recognizing one of my pairs of Google Glass

Tags: google-gdk

I had two pairs of Google glasses. One is black(original version) and the other white(new version).  I had done a lot of development using the black pair. We sent the black one back to exchange for the new version.  I tried to continue developing using the white pair but can not get adb to recognize it.

1. OS: Mac 10.8.5
2. Eclipse 4.2.1
3. Glass Firmware: XE16.11
4. ADT Package 2.3
5. Android SDK Tools 22.6.2
6. Android SDK Platform-tools 19.0.1
7. Both pairs were set to debug mode.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: i think your adb connection is down..try these commands adb kill-server and adb start-server...if every thing installed correctly

Comment: adb recognizes all Android phones I connect.

Comment: I also did a factory reset to the Google Glass and rebooted the MAC.

Comment: Does you updated your glass recently?

Comment: XE16.11 is the most recent version of Glass Firmware

Comment: there might be some bug left behind i think so.in kitkat many problems arises

Comment: I think the device is defective.  I do not think it ever worked